# Ubuntu 16.04 Whenever system restart or access folder then all hidden files and folders are appearing on screen

Tags: 16.04

Ubuntu 16.04 Whenever system restart or access folder then all hidden files and folders are appearing on screen

I am unable to find these option

**Edit** >> **Preferences** >> **Show hidden files**

Is there any global setting which I can use to hide file or folder.

Comment: What do you mean by appearing on screen? nautilus file manager or the desktop

Comment: nautilus file manager, home folder as well as all child folder

Comment: press control-H can do one-time show/hide, but you still need to go edit->preferences to choose persistent setting

Comment: If you focus on nautilus and move mouse to OS status bar on the top, menu options should come up.  Or you can focus at nautilus and press alt-e to bring up edit menu.